# NameError: name 'TypeError' is not defined in Apache logs

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, mod-wsgi

My apache error logs are full of this repeating error message. While my app works fine and apache continues to serve it I am unable to find the cause of other errors because for some reason this is the only thing being logged.

My app is a Django app running apache2 and mod-wsgi

```
NameError: name 'TypeError' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <function BaseEventLoop.__del__ at 0x7fefd6b13040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 654, in __del__
NameError: name 'ResourceWarning' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <function Local.__del__ at 0x7fefd6b0b430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/example/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/local.py", line 96, in __del__
```

Answer (score 5):

This began happening for me as well after I moved from Django2 to Django3 (and upgrading other packages and tools). Mostly, I noticed it on restarting Apache.

It appears to be related to mod-wsgi, and after digging into some other sites, I found that adding

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

to my Apache .conf files atop addition the WSGIScriptAlias, WSGIDaemonProcess, and WSGIProcessGroup settings resolved the error.

I found a debugging reference [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/789), which references further documentation.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Thanks!